# spark shell not responding from Terminal in cloudera VM Box

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When i tried to use spark-shell for the first time. The spark shell is not responding.This is what i got,

> [root@quickstart cloudera]# spark-shell WARNING: User-defined
>   SPARK_HOME
>   (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark) overrides
>   detected (/usr/lib/spark). WARNING: Running spark-class from
>   user-defined location. Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust
>   logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel)
>    Welcome to
>
> ```
>   ____              __
>  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
> _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
>   /_/
> ```
>
> Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java
>   1.7.0_67) Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.

Comment: what error does it gives after this ?

Comment: Hey Shankar, It is not responding after that...I waited for sometime but it was not all responding.

Comment: Using cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the Late response. I happened to use Spark-shell for the first time. And while using spark-shell make sure to run 'cloudera-manager' by using the Command: sudo/home/cloudera/cloudera-manager [--Express or --Enterprise] from the terminal. And Login to Cloudera Manager from Firefox. And the make sure the YARN is running if not restart YARN and restart Spark then open a new Terminal and enter : 
spark-shell.
This time it should work and sc object is Created.
Sorry if i went wrong anywhere but this is what I did.